# Microsoft SQL Server login failed for standard user

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication, windows-authentication

I'm developing a Windows Forms application which connects to a Microsoft SQL Server database. Using SQL Server authentication, the login works, also works for Windows authentication when the application is run as administrator.

The problem is when it isn't run as administrator, and it is run under a session of a Standard user, the application gives the following error:

> Cannot open database DATABASENAME requested by the login. The login failed.  Login failed for user COMPUTERNAME\USERNAME

Comment: Does that user have a) a login to the server, and b) a user account on the database? Is the database on the same machine as the application running?

Comment: a) yes, I can find it under Logins in MS SQL Server Management Studio
b) I don't understand?
and the database, yes, it is on the same machine

Comment: This is the ConnectionString that I am using: Data Source=SQLSERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME;Integrated Security=true;

Comment: So a database has two levels of authentication: the *login* lets the (windows user account) connect to the server, and then the *user* (which is linked to a login) that lets them access a particular database.

Comment: @Mark I need Windows Authentication, not SQL Server Authentication.

Comment: @TZHX I think I found it under Logins -> my user -> properties -> user mapping, so there is one user for my database

Comment: @DenisVisan but you said clearly at the top using "SQL Server authentication" .. this is counter to what you replied

Comment: @BugFinder I said it works for SQL Server authentication but doesn't work for Windows authentication as a standard user

Comment: ok, I must have misread it

Answer (score 0):

[**Login without Admin Mode**](https://serverfault.com/questions/130434/how-do-i-login-to-sql-server-without-having-to-use-run-as-administrator-when-s)

> Most likely your problem is that your database is setup to only have
>   logins defined for administrative users. Go into Management Studio as
>   an admin user, and go to the Security -> Logins category...

**Note :**

Starting with Windows Vista back in 2007, Microsoft made the very smart decision to limit the ability of applications to make key changes to a user’s PC. Only applications with administrator privileges could access important parts of Windows, and users had to specifically enable these apps to “[run as administrator](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/always-run-as-administrator/).”

[Adding manifest for .NET Applications](http://abundantcode.com/how-to-force-the-net-winforms-application-to-run-as-administrator-in-windows-8/)

> You can tun your App in Admin mode by adding a manifest file.

More reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764494/no-admin-rights-in-sql-management-studio)

Comment: Yes, under Logins I can see my user listed, what should be changed?

Answer (score 0):

The below instructions should work using SQL Server Management Studio

```
1. SQL Server mixed mode, Windows Authentication and SQL Server (right click SQL instance under Server Management -> Properties -> Security)
2. Add the login to SQL Security -> Logins
3. Add login to the Database -> Security -> Users
4. Assign user permissions for tables and stored procedures (right click table or stored procedure -> properties -> permissions -> search -> browse -> select login -> grant 'select, delete, update' for login as needed)
5. Use connection string: PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=<ip_address>,<port_number>;NETWORK LIBRARY=dbmssocn;INITIAL CATALOG=<database_name>;User ID=<user_name>;Password=<password>
```